# Populate Backpack select_from_array options() with DB query

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-backpack

I've defined a Backpack `select_from_array` column for the field `form_trx` in the table `transactions`. I want to populate the `options` array for that Backpack column with data that's stored in two columns (called `value_store` and `value_display`) of another database table (called `lookups`). I thought this would work:

from **TransactionCrudController.php**

```
 CRUD::column('form_trx') 
   -> type('select_from_array') 
   -> options(  
 function () 
 { return 
 DB::table('lookups')
   ->where('type_lookup', 'form_trx')
   ->value('value_store', 'value_display')
   ->toArray();
});
```

But it fails, saying

> Cannot use object of type Closure as array.

I think I've got some PHP details wrong in trying to supply an array to the **options()** method. Can you tell me the right syntax? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you, @PedroX. You got me onto the right track.

I now have a working pattern for populating a Backpack `select_from_array` field's `options()` method with key=>value pairs plucked from a different table (called `lookups` below) using an Eloquent query. Since that pattern may be helpful to others, I've shared it below.

This logic belongs in `<table>CrudController.php`. It's coded for a field called `form_trx` in `<table>`.

It also relies on an additional table called `lookups` that contains four columns: `value_store` and `value_display` are a key and a value, respectively, for the field named in `type_lookup`. And `sequence_lookup` controls the order in which the values will appear in the `select_from_array` field for the field named in `type_lookup`.

So here's how to collect all the keys and values stored in `lookups` that are relevant to the `form_trx` field in `<table>`; turn them into an associative array; and supply that array to a `select_from_array` field for `form_trx` in the Backpack controller for `<table>`.

First, at the top of `<table>CrudController.php`, add this line so we can use the DB facade to query the `lookups` table:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB ;
```

Then, in the `setupCreateOperation()` function, add the following:

```
        // Fetch a collection of key=>value pairs
        $options = DB::table('lookups')
                    ->where('type_lookup', 'form_trx') 
                    ->orderBy('sequence_lookup')
                    ->pluck('value_display', 'value_store')
                    ->toArray() 
                    ;

        // Set up the form_trx field in Backpack's CRUD controller
        CRUD::field('form_trx') 
        -> label('Form')
        -> type('select_from_array')  // the type of Backpack field you want
        -> allows_null(false)
        -> options($options)  // Backpack will display the value, store the key
        ;
```

You can use the same code in the `setupListOperation()` function, too. But you'll have to change `CRUD::field()` to `CRUD::column()`.

Answer (score 0):

you should pass an array not a closure to the options:

```php
$options = ['array', 'of', 'options'];

CRUD::field('my_field')->options($options);
```

Cheers